# Unrealistic billiard ball movement

Tags: unity, physics, physics-engine, sphere, billiards

So, I have this problem, even when I apply a small amount of force, the balls seem to get pushed away easily. Here's how they should behave (GIF from 8 ball pool game):

[image]

And here's how I have it :

[image]

**Rigidbody of balls:**

[image]

**Physics Material of Balls:**

[image]

**Physics Material of Table**

[image]

**Project Settings:-**
[image]

I tried playing with static friction values for the balls and table, but it doesn't seem to give me realistic results either. Does anyone know what should I do?

Note : No script is changing the behaviour of the balls either.

Comment: The balls at the bottom picture are more loosely and unevenly arranged. Maybe that has an effect.

Comment: I now changed the positioning of the balls, the problem is still there.

Comment: Have you tried playing with the mass of the balls?

Comment: Increasing mass doesn't have an effect, I tried it. What seems to have an effect is the drag. Though increasing drag doesn't really produce realistic results, it makes the balls a lot more firm, but then again, increasing drag makes the ball seem like pieces of rough wood.

Comment: The only other things that comes to my mind is increasing the mass of the white ball compared to the rest.

Comment: Your ball collusions are perfectly elastic atm (bounciness 1) — have you tried reducing that number so more energy is soaked up when chains of balls collide, such as during a break in this example?

Comment: Tried it, more or less the same result.